# Pass arguments to flask error handler

Tags: python, flask

On my website, I want to be able to give the user better feedback on a 404 error than "page not found". If a view raises a 404 error, I want to pass an extra parameter to the template that describes what the view shows. For instance:

**views.py**

```
def get_or_404(model, attribute, value, template, **kwargs):
    try:
        return session.query(model).filter(attribute == value).one()
    except NoResultFound:
        abort(404)

@app.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(error):
    return render_template("404.html"), 404

@app.route("project/<project_id>")
def project_show(project_id):
    """
    Show the files contained in a specific project.

    :param int project_id: The ID of the desired project.
    """

    project = get_or_404(Project, Project.id, project_id, "item_not_found.html", item="project")

    # Other stuff
```

If the user attempts to go to a project that does not exist, then they are sent to a 404 page. If I can provide the `item` kwarg (from `project_show`) to the template `404.html`, then the template will say, for instance, "Project not found" instead of just "page not found".

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `errorhandler` route [already has](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.errorhandler) an `error` argument. When you call `abort()`, Flask throws an `HTTPException`, which `errorhandler` is waiting for. The main idea here is that you can create your own exception hierarchy or one exception with different properties and use it in your `errorhandler` template.

The second idea is to use [flashing](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/flashing/): on exception, `flash` a message and `abort()`, then in your `errorhandler` template pick up this message.

Comment: How can I "create my own exceptions hierarchy?" Won't `HTTPException` always be thrown when I call `abort()`?

Comment: See http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/?highlight=errorhandler#flask.Flask.errorhandler, you can catch any exception with `errorhandler`. So your exception can be look like `class ProjectNotFoundException(Exception): pass` and catch with `@app.errorhandler(ProjectNotFoundException)`.